# Is there a method to read files within a dir when using a local WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a workaround or alternative to `Directory.GetFiles()` when running a WCF service under a local account?

I have a Self-Hosted WCF Service where I need to retrieve the names of all files within a directory in a network drive like `C:/`.
However, I am aware that when using a WCF Service in a local account, the service can only access directories that the Service has created.

A 'why not' run through anyway, renders this as expected:

> Cannot find part of the path 'C:/SST/DSS'

**MSDN** offers a very long and complicated workaround that involves re-writing your entire Service Interface, and messing with Threads and Components.

Will I have to move my Service to production instead of local in order to test, or is there another method to read files within a dir when using a local WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

> within a directory in a network drive. `C:/`

Do you mean `C:\`? Do you mean "a network drive, like `H:`"? `C:` is usually used for the local Windows installation.

> a local account

What account explicitly? The "local service" account, or a local service account?

> the service can only access directories that the Service has created.

Not really. It can't use drive mappings made for other users though.

> MSDN offers a very long and complicated workaround that involves re-writing your entire Service Interface, and messing with Threads and Components.

Which article did you read?

> Will I have to move my Service to production instead of local in order to test

No, development and staging should mimic your production environment. If production runs under a different user, like an AD account or the Network Service account, then you need to develop and test your service using such an  account too.

Anyway, it sounds like you should just use the full UNC path to the share, so `\\server\share\SST\DSS`.